# Fingerprint sign-in option not available

Tags: gnome, 19.04, synaptics, fingerprint-reader

I have ASUS Vivobook S15 and I'm currently running Ubuntu 19.04 on single boot. I want to make use of my fingerprint scanner to log in but there's no option for fingerprint login in the **settings/users** menu.

I also tried to install **fingerprint GUI** as well but it won't detect the fingerprint scanner.

Comment: Not all fingerprint scanners are supported on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Computer vendors rarely provide Linux drivers for fingerprint sensors. Some drivers are made using reverse engineering by enthusiasts.

So in many cases fingerprint sensors can't be used on Linux systems unless someone manages to create some driver for it.